# How to delete a certain value from all columns in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to delete a certain value from all the column in my data frame.

Data frame description:

```
    Data columns (total 13 columns):
    Column                 Non-Null Count  Dtype  
    ---  ------                 --------------  -----   
     1   age_group_5_years      34842 non-null  int64  
     2   race_eth               34842 non-null  int64  
     3   first_degree_hx        34842 non-null  int64  
     4   age_menarche           34842 non-null  int64  
     5   age_first_birth        34842 non-null  int64
```

The number inside the column indicates a category .

Example:

```
Age (years) in 5 year groups
1 = Age 18-29
2 = Age 30-34
3 = Age 35-39
```

The column contains int or float, I need to drop all the 9 values in the data frame.
9 indicates unknown values in the dataframe

Comment: I'm not sure which column you mean here, but this should work:`df = df[df["column"].ne(9)]` where [`.ne(9)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) means not equal to `9`.

Comment: what should happen if a cell contains `9`? Do you want to drop the entire row, or replace with `NaN`?

Comment: First of all, Thanks for the answer.  I would like to replace it with Nan.

Comment: what is the best method for detecting unknown values inside a data frame (Nan)?, to improve a machine learning model's accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reading between the lines here: assuming the OP wants to drop all rows where at least one column contains `9` (`int`) or `9.0` (`float`) or `9 + 0j` (`complex`):

```py
df_new = df.replace(9, np.NaN).dropna()
```

Alternatively, you can make a mask and select with it:

```py
mask = (df != 9).all(1)
df_new = df.loc[mask]
```

Reproducible example:

```py
np.random.seed(0)
n = 12
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': np.random.randint(8, 11, n),
    'y': np.random.randint(8, 11, n) * 1.0,
    'z': np.random.randint(8, 11, n) * (1.0 + 0j),
})
```

Gives:

```py
>>> df
     x     y          z
0    8   9.0   9.0+0.0j
1    9  10.0  10.0+0.0j
2    8  10.0   8.0+0.0j
3    9   8.0  10.0+0.0j
4    9   9.0   8.0+0.0j
5   10   9.0   9.0+0.0j
6    8   9.0   9.0+0.0j
7   10   9.0  10.0+0.0j
8    8   8.0   8.0+0.0j
9    8   9.0   9.0+0.0j
10   8   8.0   9.0+0.0j
11  10   8.0   9.0+0.0j
```

And:

```py
df_new = df.replace(9, np.NaN).dropna()

>>> df_new
     x     y         z
2  8.0  10.0  8.0+0.0j
8  8.0   8.0  8.0+0.0j
```

Note that, with the seed and parameters above, each column has at least one row where it is the only one to have a `9`:

```py
>>> {k: set(s.index[s])
...  for k in df.columns
...  for s in [(df[k] == 9) & ~(df.drop(k, 1) == 9).any(1)]
... }

{'x': {1, 3}, 'y': {7}, 'z': {10, 11}}
```

and these are all among the rows that are dropped from `df`. That verifies that the expression is correct and drops all rows where any value is `9` (as `int`, `float`, or `complex`).